# How to get asset caching working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, heroku, asset-pipeline

I am trying to upgrade to cedar / asset pipeline and am stuggling with something.

Everything renders fine, but my app seems noticeably slower.  Looking thorugh my logs I see tons of items like these:

> 2012-03-15T17:03:02+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [GET
>   /assets/application.js] miss 2012-03-15T17:03:02+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   cache: [GET /assets/down_arrow.gif] miss 2012-03-15T17:03:02+00:00
>   app[web.1]: cache: [GET /assets/application.css] miss

**I would expect these to be hits -- right?**

My production.rb

```
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # For nginx:
  config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect'

  # I also tried these
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = "X-Sendfile"
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = nil

  config.cache_store = :dalli_store
```

My application.rb

```
...

    config.assets.enabled = true

    # Version of your assets, change this if you want to expire all your assets
    config.assets.version = '1.0'

    config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false

    config.active_support.deprecation = :log
```

Note: that `assets:precompile` works fine on deploy:

```
-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
       Running: rake assets:precompile
-----> Rails plugin injection
       Injecting rails_log_stdout
       Injecting rails3_serve_static_assets
```

Thanks!  Let me know if you need additional information

Comment: do you see the asset-compilation in your heroku log when you deploy?

Comment: there should be something like `-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
       Running: rake assets:precompile`

Comment: yup -- i'll update the question with that info

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I raised a support ticket with heroku and here was there response:

> I'd give this a shot:
>   http://jackchu.com/blog/2011/09/20/rails-asset-pipeline-content-delivery-networks-and-rack-cache/
>
> Recent investigations Rack::Cache and memcached/dalli seems to be
>   broken in Rails 3.1+.

That seemed to do the trick.  I look forward to the interaction between Rack::Cache and dalli to be fixed, but in the mean time I will follow @jackchu approach

Comment: FYI, i found it here: http://jackchu.com/2011/09/20/rails-asset-pipeline-content-delivery-networks-and-rack-cache/

Comment: Now it's here: https://jackchu.com/articles/2011/09/20/rails-asset-pipeline-content-delivery-networks-and-rack-cache/

Answer (score -1):

you probably missed one of the many asset-pipeline configurations. have a look at my production.rb file:

```
HamburgOnRuby::Application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb

  # Code is not reloaded between requests
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # Disable Rails's static asset server (Apache or nginx will already do this)
  config.serve_static_assets = false

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS
  config.assets.compress = true

  # Don't fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed
  # config.assets.compile = false

  # Generate digests for assets URLs
  config.assets.digest = true

  # Compress both stylesheets and JavaScripts
  config.assets.js_compressor  = :uglifier
  config.assets.css_compressor = :scss

  # Defaults to Rails.root.join("public/assets")
  # config.assets.manifest = YOUR_PATH

  # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = "X-Sendfile" # for apache
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for nginx
  config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = nil # http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails31_heroku_cedar#the_asset_pipeline

  # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
  # config.force_ssl = true

  # See everything in the log (default is :info)
  # config.log_level = :debug

  # Use a different logger for distributed setups
  # config.logger = SyslogLogger.new

  # Use a different cache store in production
  # config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store

  # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server
  # config.action_controller.asset_host = "http://assets.example.com"

  # Precompile additional assets (application.js, application.css, and all non-JS/CSS are already added)
  config.assets.precompile += %w( active_admin.js active_admin.css )

  # Disable delivery errors, bad email addresses will be ignored
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    :address        => "smtp.sendgrid.net",
    :port           => "25",
    :authentication => :plain,
    :user_name      => ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME'],
    :password       => ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD'],
    :domain         => ENV['SENDGRID_DOMAIN']
  }

  # Enable threaded mode
  # config.threadsafe!

  # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation can not be found)
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  # Set the default host for production
  config.default_host = 'onruby.de'
end
```